# create new directory in Thunar, when view is full of files

Tags: thunar

To create a new directory in Thunar, I can right-click on free space in the file view, and get an entry 'new directory' in the context menu.

If the directory contains enough files to fill the whole view, there is no free space to click and get that context menu. I can only click on files then, which brings up a different context menu, depending on the file type (mime type/extension - doesn't matter here).

I'm using the detail file-view and often have too many files to solve the problem by zooming. I don't consider zooming in and out to be an acceptable part in the process of creating a directory. I don't want to perform gymnastics, but to create a directory efficiently. I'm searching for the way to do it - not for a workaround!

Versions: Xubuntu 12.04 LTS, Thunar 1.2.3

Answer (score 3):

hold the CTRL key on your keyboard and press - (minus) key for two times , so that you can get some space .

you can do that by holding CTRL  key and rolling mouse scroller .

else In preferences choose the text icons as i have did in image so that you can some space . 
 [image]

Comment: Depending on my view, the second ctrl-minus had no effect, and with much files, this doesn't work. Changing the kind of view does work, but is an annoyance, since I have to change the view back again, if I like my detail-view. I guess it isn't your fault.

Answer (score 3):

By hitting the button which indicates the current dir [image: button]

we can create a new one without ceremony.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.10 but it does not show a "Create a folder" option.

Comment: My mistake, I am on Ubuntu 12.10, so have unity. That may be the difference(?).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the same in older versions but in Thunar 1.6.3 at least you can hold down CTRL and right click a file that isn't selected and you'll get the directory context menu.