# How can I create a new blank file in an occupied directory?

Tags: nautilus

I am not experiencing the problem in [How to create a new blank file in Nautilus 3.6 and above?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208291/how-to-create-a-new-blank-file-in-nautilus-3-6-and-above), perhaps because I have a newer version of Nautilus.

```
$ nautilus --version
GNOME nautilus 3.14.2
```

I can create a blank file very easily in most directories: find some blank space, right click, and select New Document » Empty Document. However, if a folder has enough content to fill the screen, there *is* no blank space. If I switch to icon mode, there is blank space between the icons, but in list mode there is no blank space anywhere. I don’t recall having this difficulty in the past. Right clicking in list mode used to work. Is there any way I can restore older behaviour?

Comment: Related, for Thunar: http://askubuntu.com/q/233855/652.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest method is this keyboard combo: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>.

---

This basically mimics [Florian Diesch’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/632604): <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> opens “File”, <kbd>D</kbd> opens “New Documents” and <kbd>E</kbd> is for “Empty Document”.

Comment: Alt+F does not work anymore under Nautilus 3.26.x used with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver.

Answer (score 5):

If there is no blank space you have to use `New Document` » `Empty Document` from the `File` menu.

Comment: `New Document » Empty Document` does not exists anymore under Nautilus 3.26.x used with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver.

Answer (score 5):

The canonical command to create an empty file is indeed `touch`.

From the command line, enter `touch <filename(including full path)>`.

(Although, beware arguments containing spaces.)

Comment: Your solution is a workaround.  Users should not have to go to the terminal to create a new file.  Since it is a workaround that solves the problem, I vote you up.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the cd command to move to your folder step by step from the terminal and then use any editor to create a file, such as

```
cd Desktop/../..
nano a
```

This opens "**a**" file. Just save the file by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. Two dots ".." is for parent directory.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated in the case the directory is already opened in Nautilus. ------ Easier way: In a terminal (start with Ctrl+Alt+t) write: `cd ` (with a space) then drag and drop the directory from Nautilus to the terminal and press Enter. This will switch you to the directory. Then write: `touch filename` which will create an empty file named `filename`.